# Kubelet stopped posting node status (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, amazon-eks

I am running a kubernetes cluster on EKS with two worker nodes. Both nodes are showing NotReady status and when I checked the kubelet logs on both nodes, there are below errors

> k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list
>   *v1.Pod: Unauthorized k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:455: Failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:464: Failed to list *v1.Node:
>   Unauthorized

Is there anyway I can check which credentials are being used and how to fix this error?

Comment: Please add more information, It's clear that the credentials used are invalid. Check if the NS or context in which you're trying to deploy has RBAC configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I guess RBAC should be configured correctly (because it is mainly managed by AWS EKS). I was able to access the cluster untill I installed a pod (prometheus & Grafana using helm install stable/prometheus command). 
Where can I check this configuration anyways? Is there a way, I can reset kubelet configs?

Comment: Do a `kubeadm reset` followed by a `kubeadm init` to reset and rejoin. You may find the Grafana and Prometheus config under default/kube-system namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up creating new cluster for now.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as I am creating cluster using terraform. But no luck with creating new cluster. Any possible options?

Answer (score 4):

Check the `aws-auth` ConfigMap whether the Role used by the node has proper permissions. Also you enable the EKS control plane logs on cloudwatch and check the authenticator logs on what Role is being denied access.

You can reset the configmap anytime with the same user/role that was used to create the cluster, even if it is not present in the configmap.

**It is important that you do not delete this role/user from IAM.**

Comment: Thanks - you saved my Friday evening! That was the issue - the `aws-auth` CM has the wrong EC Instance Profiles set.

Comment: Hi @raveen.chandran, what do you mean for `reset the configmap`? re-editing it or removing it?